# Java program ends when logging out from x-session

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

When I run a Java program with a GUI (e.g. a simple JFrame) and then ending the X session (logout), my Java program is terminated. Java programs that don't use a GUI keep running.

There is nothing wrong with that, but I'd like to know *how* the program is terminated. I don't get messages about uncaught exceptions or other issues. The exit code is 1. If the prog was terminated by a signal, the exit code would by 128+signal (afaik).

Can someone shed some light on this issue. Can I somehow prevent program termination or control the exit code for that case?

[Edit]

I'm aware of the defaultCloseOperation. I'm using EXIT_ON_CLOSE. But this would lead to a call to System.exit(0).
I also added a WindowListener to monitor which of its functions is called when my program ends. When I finish the program by clicking on the window-X, the function windowClosing() is called. When I logout and finish the X-session so that my program is terminated, no WindowListener function is called. My program just exits with exit code 1.

Answer (score 0):

> When I run a Java program with a GUI (e.g. a simple JFrame)

I don't know how X-session works, but when using a JFrame you need to be aware of the frames

```
setDefaultCloseOperation(...);
```

method. When `EXIT_ON_CLOSE` is used, the JVM will be exited right away.

When `DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE`, the JVM will be exited if it is the last frame open and there are no other Threads running to prevent the JVM from closing.